# Unable to calculate time taken by Linux Kernel to execute hello world program written in C language

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am trying to calculate the time taken by Linux Kernel while executing the simple hello world program. I am unable to do it. I am attaching the error message. I have not attached the Makefile which is however correct to my knowledge. Any help to calculate it perfectly?

Code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/time.h> 

int init_module(void)
{ 
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    printk(“hello world\n”);
    t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printk(“%f\n”, time_taken);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) 
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT “Goodbye world\n”);
}
```

---

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QXq9.png)

Comment: The code should go into the question, with four spaces in front of every code line. And also the error message. External links should not convey essential information...

Comment: Thank you. I will try to follow the pattern as far as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?

The printk is wrong as it does not include log level and there is no 'clock()' in the kernel, but an equivalent should not be used here anyway.

If you are really interested in performance, you want to look into things like perf instead.

Except it looks like you should not kernel work just yet.

Comment: This relieves. Thank you. Also I would be interested to know if there is any built-in library to avoid usage of external tools.